# When I try to call an object method I get an unexpected answer

Tags: python

I am making a twitch.tv API wrapper for python and when I ran the following code, at `print (t.getstatus)` it would print : `<bound method twitchchannel.getstatus of <__main__.twitchchannel instance at 0x0198D3A0>>` instead of the value of the variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
import urllib2
import json

class twitchchannel():
    def __init__ (self,channel):
        self.channel = channel
        url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel
        dict1 = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
        self.status = dict1 ['status']
        self.display_name = dict1 ['display_name']
        self.mature = dict1 ['mature']
        self.chanurl = dict1 ['url']
        self.created_at = dict1 ['created_at']
        self.teams = dict1 ['teams']
        self.game = dict1 ['game']
        self.updated_at = dict1 ['updated_at']
        print dict1
    def getstatus(self):
        return self.status

t = twitchchannel('ethotv')

print (t.getstatus)
print (t.status) #This works
```

Comment: try like this : t.getstatus() ;)

Comment: I have figured it out it was a dumb mistake that my ide failed to fix. I forgot the `()` after `t.getstatus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print (t.getstatus())`. Note the extra parenthesis. The message you got was essentially pointing to an address that the method `getstatus` resides at (`instance at 0x0198D3A0`). The reaon `status` works is because it is not a method.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *call* the `t.getstatus()` method:

```
print (t.getstatus())
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 0):

You should call a function like a function :)

```
   print (t.getstatus())
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot now.

Comment: No problem, somtimes happens thing like this ;)